# Microsoft Access - reference object on a 2 layer menu navigation control

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, navigationbar

I got a form called `frm_deleteFinishGoodsInventory` which contains a combo box that has a `afterupdate`. This event works perfectly fine in a stand alone form.

[image]

When it comes to putting this form on a navigation control, I can't seem to reference the cbolotNo.

Example of a 2 layer menu navigation control

[image]

As you can see, I am in the menu Shipping (1st layer) + Delete Carton From FGI (2nd layer) -> targeting the `frm_deleteFinishGoodsInventory`.

I have tried multiple things, but I always end up with the same error or the program crashing since I can't reference the object.

frm_NavMenu = main navigation form

NavigationButton26 = 1st menu layer ( Shipping )

NavigationButton819 = 2nd menu layer ( Delete Carton From FGI )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing this to:

DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[lotNo] = " & Me!cboLotNo